# Вывод объектов из словаря python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть особенность. Когда я вывожу элементы из словаря, они оказываются упорядоченными в порядке добавления. С другой стороны, никто не гарантирует порядка элементов в словаре.

```
d = {}
for i in range(20):
    d[i] = i

for k in d.items():
    print(k)

for k in d:
    print(k, d[k])
```

- Закреплен ли где-нибудь в стандарте подход к организациии словаря?
- Каким образом словарь реализован?
- Гарантируется ли порядок вывода?

Comment: Changed in version 3.7: Dictionary order is guaranteed to be insertion order. [mapping-types-dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с python 3.6 для CPython реализации порядок элементов в словаре будет именно в порядке добавления. Начиная с python 3.7 это стало не просто фичей реализации, а фичей языка.

Словарь организован в виде двух массивов. Первый - массив данных, куда записываются новые элементы. Для быстрого поиска есть второй разреженный массив, содержащий индексы для массива с данными.

Выглядит это внутри CPython вот так

```
struct dict {
    long num_items;
    variable_int *sparse_array;
    dict_entry* compact_array;
}

struct dict_entry {
    long hash;
    PyObject *key;
    PyObject *value;
}
```